Ramification of Prime Ideals in the Case of Degree [K:F]
The following proposition is from Number Theory by H. Koch.
Here, $\Gamma$ is a PID, $P$ is the quotient field of $\Gamma$, $K$ is a finite separable extension of $P$, $F$ is an intermediate field of $K/P$, and $O$ and $\mathfrak{o}$ are the integral closures of $\Gamma$ in $K$ and $F$ respectively.
$\mathbf{Proposition 3.10.3.}$
Let $\mathfrak{P}$ be a prime ideal of $O$ whose ramification index
$e$ over $F$ is equal to $[K : F]$. Furthermore, let $\pi$ be an element of $O$ with
$\nu_{\mathfrak{P}}(\pi)=1$. Then $K = F (\pi)$, and the minimal polynomial of $\pi$ has the form
$f_{\pi}(x)=x^e+\cdots+a_{e-1}x+a_{e}$
with
$\nu_{\mathfrak{p}}(a_{i})\geq1$ for $i=1,...,e$
and $\nu_{\mathfrak{p}}(a_{e})=1$
$\mathbf{Proof.}$ Since $\nu_{\mathfrak{P}}(\pi)=1$, we have that $\mathfrak{P}\cap F(\pi)$ has ramification index over
$F$ greater than or equal to $e$. (skip the rest)
I understand that this argument is sufficient to conclude that $e = [K:F
]$, but I'm not sure how he derived it. Could you please help?
